# localscroll.js - Can not seem to figure out how to set up the links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have only just been introduced to HTML code 3 days ago and have not learnt much and this would probably be an easy fix but the title says it all. I am unsure on how to set up the page links so I can use the smooth scrolling jQuery plugin, localscoll.js. Oh and im trying to link .section2 to .arrow and servers.png

**Javascript**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function( $ ){
        $.localScroll.defaults.axis = 'xy';
        $.localScroll({
            target: '#content',
            queue:true,
            duration:1000,
            hash:true,
            onBefore:function( e, anchor, $target ){
            },
            onAfter:function( anchor, settings ){
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="section1">
    <div class="menubar">
      <div class="menubar fadeInUp animated">
         <a href="#section2"><img class="menutext" src="images/menu_bar/servers.png">    </a>   
      </div>    
      <div class="banner wow fadeInUp animated" data-wow-delay="0.75s" />
         <a href="#section2"><img class="arrow wow fadeIn animated" data-wow-delay="0.75s" src="css/banner/arrow.png"></a>
        </div>
    </div>    
    <div class="section2">
        <a name="section2"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.arrow {
   margin-top: 470px;
   text-align: center;
}

.section2 {
   background: url(section2/background.png);
   background-position: center;
   width: 100%;
   height: 515px;
   margin-bottom: 0;
   position: relative;
}
```

Comment: maybe you could post a working JSfiddle or JSBin?

Answer (score 0):

According to localscroll.js (and the common ref links), the href attribute (#section2) should be the target's id.

Try change the `class` for `ID`

```
<div id="#section2">
    <a name="section2"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey I have tried this and I believe you are correct, however, the url changes to /index.html#section2 and the page does not scroll at all.